# Org-table running total column formula

Tags: org-table

Is it possible to write an org table colmun formula which calculates the running total of some other column? Here is a simple example of the idea: The table

```
|  1 |   |
|  2 |   |
|  5 |   |
| 10 |   |
```

should be endowed with a column formula which gives the resulting table

```
|  1 |  1 |
|  2 |  3 |
|  5 |  8 |
| 10 | 18 |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add from the first row to the current row thus:

```
| value | accum |
|-------+-------|
| 1     | 1     |
| 2     | 3     |
| 5     | 8     |
| 10    | 18    |
|-------+-------|
#+TBLFM: $2=vsum(@I$1..$1)
```

`@I` refers to the row after the first hline. If you don't want headings in your table, use `@1` instead.

Of course this is not super efficient for large tables since the whole sum is calculated each time. You can calculate the sum progressively as follows:

```
| value | accum |
|-------+-------|
| 1     | 1     |
| 2     | 3     |
| 5     | 8     |
| 10    | 18    |
|-------+-------|
#+TBLFM: @2$2=$1::$2=$1+@-1
```

although I'm not sure if this second method is faster.

Comment: The second one requires the formula to be evaluated twice, in order to converge on the correct result.